Is it possible to fully deallocate the Memory used by Realm
When you initialize a flexible sync Realm in Swift with a RLMApp and User, it takes up about 20MB of memory, according to the debugger. When you .logout of the app, invalidate the realm, and remove all references to the users however, you get none of that memory back. My question is, is it possible to uninitialize RealmSwift in a way to reclaim some of that memory
My Use Case
I am making a WidgetExtension for my app, and need to fetch data in real time, without the user necessarily entering in the app where I could manually refresh the widget timeline. The app uses MongoDB and realm sync to store its data, so I figured I could initialize a flexible realm in the widget when I needed to fetch data and later invalidate it. Apple however, imposes a 30MB limit on the memory of widgets, so when I'm done pulling the data from the realm, I need to invalidate it and reclaim its memory so I can continue to render the widget.
Reproducible Test
Here is a short demo that highlights the issue, along with some of my attempted solutions.
class RealmManager: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared: RealmManager = RealmManager()
    
    @Published var app: RealmSwift.App? = nil
    @Published var realm: Realm? = nil
    
    
    @MainActor
    func loadRealm() async {
        self.app = RealmSwift.App(id: "APP-ID")
        let credentials = Credentials.userAPIKey("API-KEY")
        let user = try! await app!.login(credentials: credentials)
        
        let configuration = user.flexibleSyncConfiguration()
        
        let realm = try! await Realm(configuration: configuration,
                                     downloadBeforeOpen: .never )

        self.realm = realm
    }
    
    @MainActor
    private func removeSubscriptions() async {
        let subs =  self.realm!.subscriptions
        
        try! await subs.update { subs.removeAll() }
    }
    
    //MARK: Clean
    
    @MainActor
    func cleanRealm() async {
        
        await removeSubscriptions()
        
        _ = try! Realm.deleteFiles(for: Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration)
        
        try! await self.app!.currentUser?.remove()
        
        self.realm!.invalidate()
        
        self.realm = nil
        self.app = nil
        
        /// this is a function defined on RLMApp that erases all references to it throughout the codebase
        App.resetAppCache()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var realmManager = RealmManager.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("REALM: \(RealmManager.shared.realm != nil)" )
        Text("APP: \(RealmManager.shared.app != nil)" )
        
        /// when first clicked the memory spikes to around 45MB, but does not come down when 'clean' is run
        Button {
            Task { await RealmManager.shared.loadRealm() }
        } label: {
            Text("load")
        }
        
        Button {
            Task { await RealmManager.shared.cleanRealm() }
        } label: {
            Text("clean")
        }
        
    }
}


I've been digging around in Instruments and the Memory graph tool in Xcode trying to see what references are holding on to the memory, but haven't been able to find anything that helps. Not sure if this is possible, or if Realm really just doesnt have the ability to deallocate all its memory, but any guidance would be appreciated.

Have you tried filing an issue in their GitHub Realm Swift? I believe you can interact directly with the team over there.

I have not, I will post one now.. thanks!

Not sure what the purpose of the code is. The RealmManager is an ObserverableObject; it's being observed. If the memory it occupies were to be released, it would no longer notify of changes and be observable. Additionally, Realm objects are lazy-loaded; they take up a very small footprint so thousands of objects will not have much impact. If the desired result is to connect to Realm, get objects and then release Realm, that's not the right code; moreover, if that's done, those objects will need to be stored in Swift, which will take a lot more memory. Some clarity may help produce an answer.

Also - where are you adding subscriptions or defining the object types to Sync? e.g. subs.append(some query subscription or objectTypes?
